# Texture disappears when "Render Image" is clicked

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

The main screen before clicking "render image":

[image]

Page 1 of the options (pages made by scrolling):

[image]

Page 2 of the options (pages made by scrolling):

[image]

I am very, very new to Blender, so bare with me.

I had a friend make a model for me.  He assigned two textures to two objects called "Cube" and "white."  Each works properly when the render view is closed, but when I generate a render, no matter what pose, all textures disappear, and the model is solid black without shading.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you using Cycles or Blender Internal?

Comment: Blender Internal, I think?  It's the one on blender.org.  It is updated to version 2.79b, and its download button is on the home page.

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of your scene. And of the settings. Can be multiple things.

Comment: Hi.  Yes, I can.  I'll place google drive links here.  I don't use imgur etc so...

Comment: [Edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/110296/edit) these images (as inline images not google drive links) / details into your question.

Comment: ah.  I didn't see the button.

Comment: There.  The topic is updated with inline images.

Comment: Ah!  I forgot Blender needs a light object too, and my modeler removed it so it could be ported to SFM.  Thanks!

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Scott Milner, the issue has been solved.

A light source needed added.